# Selenium vba xpath contains text

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath

I am working on a selenium vba macro. I want to fetch the td element containing "18" by Xpath.

Following is my html.

```
<table class="text-center"><thead><tr><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Sun</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Mon</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Tue</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Wed</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Thu</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Fri</small></td><td class="text-muted" style="padding: 5px;"><small>Sat</small></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">1</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">2</td></tr><tr><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">3</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">4</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">5</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">6</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">7</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">8</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">9</td></tr><tr><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">10</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="bg-primary">11</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">12</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">13</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">14</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">15</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">16</td></tr><tr><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">17</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">18</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">19</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">20</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">21</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">22</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">23</td></tr><tr><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">24</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;">25</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">26</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">27</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">28</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">29</td><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">30</td></tr><tr><td style="cursor: pointer; padding: 5px;" class="invalid-calendar-date">31</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I tried all like

```
"//attribute::*[contains(.,'18')]"
"//tr/td[contains(text(),'18')]"
"//td[contains(string(),"18")]"
```

but I couldn't fetch the element.

If I use CSS selector then it works fine. But as the date changes CSS path does not change automatically. It would be great help if I could fetch the element using Xpath and the value.

Comment: Based on  the DOM. Your second option should work. This also should //td[contains(text(),'18')] work.

Comment: Share your css selector which is working and also more piece of html to find the issue

Comment: @lapimpale Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML including the parent `<tr>`

Comment: More HTML and can you include the URL? And can you explain the relevance of your comment _ But as the date changes CSS path does not change automatically._  XPath is also prone to breakage. Why exactly doesn't CSS selector work please? And of course, please include your vba code.

Comment: Updated the outer html. Please suggest the correct change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below xpath will work:

`//td[text()='18' and contains(@style,'')]`

Comment: Bonus points for describing your code and why it would solve the OP's question. For example: I do not understand how adding `contains(@style,'')` helps anything in this case.

Comment: @SiKing, most of the times, `@style` attribute will be removed by js function if the element is not visible. In this case, if there is any hidden element with the same tag and text value, it will be ignored and the one which is displayed will be selected. user's query is most likely to be the same case. I have encountered similar behaviors earlier.

Comment: You should edit this explanation into your answer. People looking for answers will usually not go looking through comments. Also, I believe `contains(@style,'')` and simply `@style` are equivalent in this case.